# Installing laravel on existing project

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php, bitbucket

I'm developing a laravel application and my computer die.
Now I want to get my project from the repository (Bitbucket + Git) but thanks to the git ignore file, the vendor folder is missing. I can't do a composer install on my project because is not allowed (the directory should be empty). The structure of my project is the same as the laravel installation except that I renamed the public folder.

I found this thread but did not solve my problem.

[Integrating existing project by laravel framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293699/integrating-existing-project-by-laravel-framework)

I wanna know the best practice or way to do this and i don't think that copy and paste the folder of my project to a fresh install of larevel should be the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to your www folder

```
cd /var/www
```

Git clone your application (not that here the directory must not exist):

```
git clone https://github.com/antonioribeiro/application
```

CD into the folder

```
cd application
```

Execute composer update (if you are in a development environment)

```
composer update
```

Or execute composer install (if you are in a production environment)

```
composer install
```

Note that for composer install or composer update, the folder may actually have files and even a vendor folder created, there is not such obstacle.

Comment: I guess you need to `composer install` instead of `composer update` when you are running the application for the first time after you clone the codes from a remote git repository. This will create necessary directories (for example, vendor), download necessary files and generate necessary files. `composer update` gives me some errors as it expects some files in the vendor directory while updating, as there is no vendor directory.

Comment: But `composer update` created 'vendor' folder in my case :)